# How to search for mutiple search parameters in Python's re library

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search for the strings in the brackets using the re.search method. From my examples of x, I am only able to properly find 'Parkwoods', I am not able to find any of the other strings.

This is what I have been doing initially, adding in \s for whitespaces etc., but I am still unable to find Garden District, Ryerson and Regent Park / Harbourfront

```
match = re.search(r"\((\w+)\)", x)
```

where x can equal

```
North York(Parkwoods)
Downtown Toronto(Garden District, Ryerson)  
Downtown Toronto(Regent Park / Harbourfront)
```

How do I pass in multiple search parameters to the `search` method? And how do I search for a forward slash?

Comment: Use the ```|``` pipe symbol between them

Comment: try this `\([^)]+\)`, [`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/BjpmSe/1/)

Comment: @CodeManiac That works! can you explain what's going on?

Comment: It means `[^)]+` match anything one or more time until `)`. and i believe you will not have `)` in between `()` else it will capture only upto first `)`

Comment: @CodeManiac, it would be more accurate to say, "match" one or more characters other than `)`", as your wording does not make clear whether `)` is included or what happens if there is no `)` later in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

`\((\w|,| |\/)+\)`

In terms of code: `re.search(r"\((\w|,| |\/)+\)", x)`

Explanation:

(    and    ) :   match the outermost parentheses

(      )+ :one or more of whatever's within the ( ), used to indicate "or"

\w|,| |/ : match alpha-numeric OR comma "," OR " " (space" OR "/" (backslash, which we escape like "/")

Try playing around on: https://regexr.com/

Edit: other comments build on the negated set [^)], but this would match ANY character not a right parens. You might want to impose stricter rules based on your application. For instance, it'd match `(&&&*$$)` in Downtown Toronto`(&&&*$$)`, which is something you may or may not want.